# How can you get Beautiful Evil Lord on Spirit Forest?

Tags: half-minute-hero

Even after upgrading my maximum mana a couple of times I always seem to take too much time.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

The victory condition for this level is to simply touch the Earth Spirit at the end. All you need to do is make yourself an opening through your opposition and touch your future Fabulous Four minion of Earth.